# Plot time-series data with a line for each year

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, seaborn

I have a dataframe containing stock data over 20 years.

```
Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume
Date                        
2001-01-02  1.062500    1.089286    1.040179    1.062500    0.930781    113078000
2001-01-03  1.035714    1.191964    1.031250    1.169643    1.024641    204268400
2001-01-04  1.295759    1.321429    1.200893    1.218750    1.067660    184849000
2001-01-05  1.209821    1.241071    1.147321    1.169643    1.024641    103089000
2001-01-08  1.209821    1.213170    1.138393    1.183036    1.036374    93424800
```

What I want is to plot every year(price) separately in the same chart,  Starting in January ending in December.

I try something like this, but plots one year after another

```
  for year in range(2001,2019):
    aapl['Close'].loc[str(year)].plot(figsize=(18,8), label=str(year), secondary_y=True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by Scott, you can plot the series against `dayofyear`, and `seaborn` helps you do by using the `hue` parameter to separate the data by the `'Year'`.

**Tested in `python 3.12.0`, `pandas 2.1.1`, `matplotlib 3.8.0`, `seaborn 0.13.0`**

### Extract or create additional data

```py
# Date is in the index, so reset
df = df.reset_index()

# verify column is a datetime dtype
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# extract the Year, which will be used for the color
df['Year'] = df.Date.dt.year

# extract the day of the year for the x-axis
df['DoY'] = df.Date.dt.day_of_year
```

### Plot with an `Axes-level` method

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='DoY', y='Close', hue='Year', legend='full', ax=ax)
sns.move_legend(ax, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False, ncols=3)
```

[image]

### Plot with a `Figure-level` method

```py
g = sns.relplot(kind='line', data=df, x='DoY', y='Open', hue='Year', legend='full', height=7, aspect=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I change a little bit to use date as index

```
sns.lineplot(x=aapl.index.dayofyear, 
             y=aapl['Close'], 
             hue=aapl.index.year)
```

*note: sns.lineplot work after seaborn 0.9