# I have a datetime dataframe that only has the summer months. How do I plot so that it is continuous instead of being separated by year?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, datetime

As I mentioned in the title, I have a datetime dataframe I have edited to only include summer months. When I go to plot it, this is what it looks like. How do I fix it so there aren't gaps between the years?[Plot of current data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9WrP.png)

I haven't been sure where to start with this, except to convert it from a datetime, but I don't really want to do that.

Comment: How would you draw it with pen and paper?

Comment: Convert your datetime as string?

Comment: Welcome to SO. 1) Feels like  duplicate. I've seen this before. Have you searched for a similar question? 2) If I am mistaken, please provide a little sample of input data (see [mre], [ask] for guidance)

Comment: Please make it clearer what you mean with "so there aren't gaps between the years". a) Would you like the time axis to skip the gaps? https://stackoverflow.com/q/65562664/12846804 Or, b) would you like the plot to just not plot the line that connects over the gaps? https://stackoverflow.com/q/41890749/12846804

Comment: 1. `df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'])` 2. `df['Year'] = df['date_col'].dt.year` 3. `df['DoY'] = df['date_col'].dt.day_of_year` 4. `import seaborn as sns` 5. `sns.lineplot(data=df, x='DoY', y='value_col', hue='Year')` [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrIto.png)

Comment: Probably duplicate of [Plot multiple years in chart overlapping the other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57208738/7758804)

Comment: Yes, there is a zoo of such questions only slightly varying around how to skip gaps in a plot. The two i linked to are only a sample. Search: `python pandas plot time year gap site stackoverflow.com`. There are not all recent. Would there be material for a review post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

*Difficult to help you without any other information.*

Suppose you have the following dataframe:

```
>>> df
      Datetime   temp
0   2021-06-21  76.66
1   2021-06-22  81.79
2   2021-06-23  68.95
3   2021-06-24  84.59
4   2021-06-25  65.41
..         ...    ...
265 2023-09-14  82.87
266 2023-09-15  70.50
267 2023-09-16  76.81
268 2023-09-17  75.20
269 2023-09-18  73.11

[270 rows x 2 columns]

>>> df.groupby(df['Datetime'].dt.year)['Datetime'].agg(['min', 'max'])
                min        max
Datetime                      
2021     2021-06-21 2021-09-18
2022     2022-06-21 2022-09-18
2023     2023-06-21 2023-09-18
```

If you want something like the figure below, you can do:

```
xticks = df.loc[df['Datetime'].dt.day.eq(1), 'Datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
vlines = df.groupby(df['Datetime'].dt.year)['Datetime'].idxmax()[:-1]
ax = df.plot(y='temp', rot=45)
ax.set_xticks(xticks.index, xticks)
ax.vlines(vlines, ymin=df['temp'].min(), ymax=df['temp'].max(), color='red', ls='dashed')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

[Minimal Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

period0 = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2021-06-21', periods=90, freq='D'))
period1 = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2022-06-21', periods=90, freq='D'))
period2 = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2023-06-21', periods=90, freq='D'))
df = pd.concat([period0, period1, period2], axis=0, ignore_index=True).to_frame('Datetime')
df['temp'] = np.round(65 + np.random.random(90*3) * 20, 2)
```